# Use of 'late' for resurrected people

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

My question concerns the use of the word *late* when referring to someone who has died.

Numerous fictional characters die and return to life again. Would it be correct to refer to them as **the late XXXX**, given that they don't stay dead? What word could be used for them at the time they are 'not alive'?

Comment: You can use `>!` at the beginning of a line to create a hidden "spoiler" section of text that has to be moused over to be read.

Comment: I would consider reformatting the question to be more generic: it also applies to Buffy the Vampire Slayer, Kenny from South Park, and [too many more to mention](http://www.buzzfeed.com/donnad/21-resurrected-fictional-characters).

Comment: It may sound odd, but I think that the most accurate adjective to use in describing the period during a person who later came back to life was dead would be "then-dead." The reason it sounds odd is that we don't have much experience in real life with the phenomenon of people dying and later coming back to life.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using both - depending on the context? When they're alive (after death and resurrection) use *resurrected* (or *reanimated*) and when they're dead use *late*.

Answer (score 1):

You could always refer to them as the *temporarily deceased*, or the *previously deceased*. Other possibilities are the *then-dead* or *once-dead* XXXX.

If someone is interacting with them whilst they are dead, you could always talk about the *body of* XXXX. This implies that they are lifeless at the time of the interaction, one wouldn't generally talk about interacting with the body of someone who is alive/conscious.

Post-resurrection you could refer to them as the *undead/undying* XXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definitions I can find, it seems only to apply to dead people.  As such, I don't know that it would be appropriate to refer to a now-living XXXX (or whatever character) as the late XXXX.

However, contemporaneous with the time he's dead, it would be appropriate, because we don't know that he's going to come back.

It might be used after the fact to call attention to that time in a light-hearted manner.  For example, I could address Harry Potter with, "When you were the late Harry Potter, Hermione was at least glad you hadn't been expelled."

Comment: _extemporaneous_? Shouldn't that be _contemporaneous_?

Comment: @Barmar Details...details...

Answer (score 0):

You could use "formerly late", which might be a little flippant, but if we're talking about fictional undead, it probably would not be offensive.